# How to write resizable page with iframe?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe, resize

I have an iframe in the same domain as the web page.

I have a header that I would like to keep the same height (I don't know what it is, let's say 80px), while the body contains the iframe, which is resized when the browser is resized:

```
----------        --------------
| header |        |   header   |
----------        --------------
| iframe |   ->   |            |
|        |        |            |
|        |        |    ....    |
----------        |            |
                  |            |
                  --------------
```

I am using jQuery and have tried `height()` and `css()` on the `iframe` div, but those do not change the `iframe`'s dimensions. The `iframe` remains at the same, small, default dimensions.

If I manually specify percentages in the `iframe` CSS, then resizing works, but because these are percentages, the `iframe` goes beyond the immediate page's borders and gets cut off after a high enough percent value pushes its borders off the screen.

I need some way to help the `iframe` compute its own borders by pixels, so that it stays within the borders of the page. I can grab the window width and height, but as mentioned, applying `css()` and `height()` from those values did not update the `iframe`'s size.

*Again: I am working with the `iframe` in the same domain as the parent page.*

How would I properly code the resizing of *both* the header and iframe, so that a `resize()` operation (or resizing the browser window) actually works?

The code I have tried is something like the following:

```
<html>
<head>
... // load jquery, etc.
<script>
function resize() { 
    var w = $('#body').width(); 
    var h = $('#body').height();

    $('#header').width(w + "px"); // works
    $('#header').height("80px"); // works

    $('#my_iframe').css("width", w + "px"); // doesn't work
    $('#my_iframe').width(w + "px"); // doesn't work, either

    $('#my_iframe').css("height", (h-80) + "px"); // doesn't work
    $('#my_iframe').height((h-80) + "px"); // doesn't work, either
}
</script>
</head>

<body onresize="resize()" id="body">
<div id="header"><div>
<iframe id="my_iframe" .../>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: So to confirm, are you setting dimensions on the iframe tag itself? I was confused when you said "on the iframe div". My approach would be to listen for window resize and then, in the event callback, set dimensions on the iframe tag equal to the body width and the body height minus the height of the header.

Comment: Are you trying to keep the page filled out with an `iframe` less an `80px` section at the top? Or should the `iframe` be able to resize it's parent window?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bind the `resize` event on the `window`, and set the height of the `iframe`:

```
$('#content').css('height', ($(window).height() - 80) + 'px');
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/t4b4j/